# i get gradle error when adding ( apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services')

Tags: android

app level gradle

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    //compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
    //compile 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-drive:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
    compile 'org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped:org.jbundle.util.osgi.wrapped.org.apache.http.client:4.1.2'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

when I remove apply ( plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' )there is no problem but after adding it I get  (Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'.

> Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information about the latest version is available at https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of com.google.android.gms to 10.0.1.)

root level gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: have you included the classpath?

Comment: Do you have anything in `libs` folder?

Comment: yes I did but not solving the problem

Comment: Could you please share both your build.gradle?

Comment: I have just edit my post I added my root gradle script

Comment: the same with me. if I add that plugin I encounter that error.. Have you fixed it already?